# R: I can't install package "drc" in R 3.0.1

Tags: linux, r, installation, package

I used R (2.15.3) with the Dose-Rresponse-Curve package (drc). Now i installed Linux Mint 16 and R in version 3.0.1. But is try to install the package drc I get an error. Has someone an idea what i can to? I have already re-installed R. Is it because the new version? Or is there an other reason. I use Linux Mint 16.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Error:

```
> install.packages("drc")
Installing package into ‘/home/thomas/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependency ‘gtools’

versuche URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/gtools_3.4.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 56047 bytes (54 Kb)
URL geöffnet
==================================================
downloaded 54 Kb

versuche URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/drc_2.3-96.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 233535 bytes (228 Kb)
URL geöffnet
==================================================
downloaded 228 Kb

* installing *source* package ‘gtools’ ...
** Paket ‘gtools’ erfolgreich entpackt und MD5 Summen überprüft
** libs
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -O3 -pipe  -g  -c setTCPNoDelay.c -o setTCPNoDelay.o
In file included from setTCPNoDelay.c:1:0:
/usr/share/R/include/R.h:28:20: fatal error: stdlib.h: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
 #include <stdlib.h>
                    ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [setTCPNoDelay.o] Fehler 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘gtools’
* removing ‘/home/thomas/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/gtools’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘gtools’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘gtools’ is not available for package ‘drc’
* removing ‘/home/thomas/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/drc’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘drc’ had non-zero exit status
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a problem with `gtools` on linux-x86_64. The [CRAN Check Results](http://cran.r-project.org/web/checks/check_results_gtools.html) return an error message. You can install previous versions of `gtools` in the [CRAN Archive](http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/gtools/). Try installing a previous version of `gtools` and then `drc` again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If tried every version of `gtools`, but nothing worked. Now I tried to installed an older version of R and get this error while compiling: `configure: error: No F77 compiler found`. But `gcc` is installed.